# Generate Entitities in separate folder

Tags: c#, wpf

Like you can see on the image

http://i51.tinypic.com/xoe14j.jpg

I have an Folder Server with the VDB.Data Class Library. In that class library i have my VDB edmx. But i wonna have my generated entities in een other folder. They must come in the Common Folder under the VDB.Common.Model --> Entities --> Generated

In the edmx are Customer ,Order , Orderdetails
Then must under the generated file be a VDBEntities.tt with underneath the following entities 
Customer, Order, Orderdetails

But how must i do that? I only can do it under the VDB.Data Library
Anybody who can help me?

Comment: Have you tried moving the generated .edmx file?

Comment: It's not the edmx that needs on the other folder but the entities. But that's 1 big file, i want the entities in separate file's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't and don't want to put the entities in separate files. You should not modify the generated files.

All of the entities are implemented as `partial` classes by the framework. This means that you can extend the code in a separate file.

For example, if you want to add a calculated property to the `Customer` class, create a `Customer.cs` file ***in the folder of your choosing***, and declare it with the `partial` keyword:

```
public partial class Customer
{
    public int CalculatedTotalOrders
    {
        get { return this.Orders.Sum(o => o.Total); }
    }
}
```

Although you've only declared one property *in this file*, you can access any of the properties of the class; the declaration is just split among multiple files -- in this case one generated file (that you don't touch) and one file of your making.

Comment: I have seen some code where the entities are in separate folders and in separate files. There is an map Entities/Generated wit the ...Entities.tt with there under the Generated Entitites. And a map Entities/General with all partial classes , like you said. But i don't know how they did that.

Comment: @SvenVdb Are you sure they were just using Entity Framework, and not custom T4 templates? .tt files are T4 templates.

Comment: It could be that they use T4 Templates. I don't know. That's why i ask it here. :) Do you know how T4 Templates work? How can i set this up.

Comment: @SvenVdb Here is a link to get you started: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2009/01/22/customizing-entity-classes-with-t4.aspx

Comment: They say to click on the following item “Add New Artifact Generation Item…”  in the edmx. But i have only the normal "Add Code Generation Item" :s